# Play JavaScript router: what is list of routes?

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am following this [doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting) to make a websocket with the JavaScript routers, but i don't know how to do with the second parameter of @helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(..???..), can anyone help me ? Thanks!